# using map in pojo object not mapping the request

Tags: java, json, mongodb, rest, morphia

I am creating a RESTful APIs.
I am doing a `@POST` call and the request body is as below:

```
{
    "user": "test1",
    "animals": {
        "cat": "3",
        "dog": "5",
        "cow": "10"
    }
}
```

Service is :

```
@Path("/saveOwnerData")
    @POST
    @Produces({ "text/html", "application/json", "application/text" })
    public Response saveOwnerData(OwnerData ownerData) {
    //Save to db
}
```

Entity object:

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity(value = "OwnerData", noClassnameStored = true)
public class OwnerData {

@Id
private String _id;
private String user;
private Map<String, String> animals;

public String get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public void set_id(String _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

public String getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public Map<String, String> getAnimals() {
    return animals;
}

public void setAnimals(Map<String, String> animals) {
    this.animals = animals;
}
```

}

**Questions:**

- The request is mapping only "user" data not the "animals" data
- I tried to do with org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject as well, same issue
- If I can't do it with map or json object, how can i map this kind of request directly to POJO

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: everything looks too fine.. anything else extra you might have missed ??

Comment: Yes! strange right? what datatype do you suggest Map or JSONObject?

Comment: You could use jackson for that